# alter element in array with html tag, then display that array

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am working on a word frequency app, where the user can find the most used word in the text and alter that word and display an altered version of the whole text in HTML.

I created a function where you create a `span` tag around the altered word, so I can give a class to add some CSS to highlight it.

```
    const updatedTextArr = text.map(word => {
        const isSameWord = word === mostUsedWord
        if (isSameWord) {
            const spanNode = document.createElement("span")
            const alteredWord = `foo${mostUsedWord}bar`
            spanNode.append(alteredWord)
            word = spanNode
            return word
        } else {
            return word
        }
        const createString = updatedTextArr.join(" ").toString()
        setTextData(createString)
    })
```

But in this way, when I console.log it, the returned altered word in a text array shows as "HTML element"

and when I display the "createString", it shows altered words as same as "HTML elements" in the view.

I wonder what is the better way to add a span tag to the found most used word?

Comment: So you return from the function? How are the last two lines going to be executed?

Comment: I can see unreachable code in the snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Map` and `array.reduce` you can solve this problem.

```js
const highlight = (text = "") => {
  const words = text.split(/\W/g);
  const wordMap = words.reduce((m, word) => {
    if (!m[word]) m[word] = 0;
    m[word] = (m[word] || 0) + 1;
    return m;
  }, {});
  let mostUsedWord = { count: 0, word: "" };
  for (let word in wordMap) {
    if (mostUsedWord.count < wordMap[word]) {
      mostUsedWord = { count: wordMap[word], word };
    }
  }
  return words.map(word => {
    if (word === mostUsedWord.word) {
      word = `<span class="highlighted">${word}</span>`;
    }
    return word;
  });
};

const createString = highlight(
  "This is a book of life. Which is never found in the jungle."
).join(" ");
console.log(createString);
document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = createString
```

```css
.as-console-row {color: red!important}

.highlighted {color: red!important}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your last two lines are inside the function, they should be outside. If you want the entire element as text, you can use `outerHTML`. Also, no need for an `else` statement since you return the word in any case.

```
const updatedTextArr = text.map( word => {
    const isSameWord = word === mostUsedWord
    if ( isSameWord ) {
        const spanNode = document.createElement( "span" )
        const alteredWord = `foo${ mostUsedWord }bar`
        spanNode.append( alteredWord )
        word = spanNode.outerHTML
    }  
    return word
} )

const createString = updatedTextArr.join( " " ).toString()
setTextData( createString )
```

This would return something like `"one <span>footwobar</span> three"` (if most used word is two).